# Visual Studio 2022 .razor code block is flickering

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, blazor-webassembly

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise. While working with `.razor` files I have a strange flickering.

Since a while my syntax highlighting is broken. As you can see in the image below it is a constant flickering of the highlighting.
Does anyone knows how to get rid of the flickering in a `.razor` file in C#. This behavior is occurring in some of the file, not in all.

I have already rebuild and clean up the project. Closing VS or the tab does not work either.

[image]

Ignore the code content, that is still in development :)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling vs?

Comment: @WiktorZychla No i haven´t. I will do this in case nothing else will work :)

Comment: It is more of a graphics card driver issue. Also note if you made any changes in the screen resolution etc

Comment: Try turning off [hardware graphics acceleration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/general/ide/performance-crash-issue)?

Comment: Does [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/code-editor-font-colors-are-flickering/1669095) can help you? You can try to install the most recent release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ (VS 2022 17.2 Preview 2).

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla Reinstalling it did not help :(

Comment: @Jingmiao Xu-MSFT this solved my problem, thank you very much! I was already extremly anoying

Comment: @stuartd that does not solved it either :(

Comment: I have 17.2.0 installed, and issue is there. I've uninstalled and reinstalled VS, no luck. Super annoying... Anyone seen anything beyond 17.2 or uncollapsing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/code-editor-font-colors-are-flickering/1669095).
A fix for this issue has been released! Install the most recent release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.

Update to 17.2 can solve the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue and just downloaded preview 17.2 Preview 6... this did not fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

While update 17.2 makes it a little better the workaround for now is to maximize all collapsed code blocks.

Comment: Good to know! Will try that next time the flickering occurs!